# How to import data from text file to the scheduling app?

Tags: java, arrays, text, split

I need to import specially formatted text file for the scheduler, as time pressure is really high, I decided to seek help and learn it better in the future. File format looks like this:

```
2 0 1 3 5 4 t 1 3 6 7 3 6   
1 2 4 5 0 3 t 8 5 10 10 10 4   
2 3 5 0 1 4 t 5 4 8 9 1 7   
1 0 2 3 4 5 t 5 5 5 3 8 9   
2 1 4 5 0 3 t 9 3 5 4 3 1  
1 3 5 0 4 2 t 3 3 9 10 4 1
```

Each row represents one activity, numbers before t represent workers and numbers after t - durations corresponding to the workers.

So far i figured out it should look something like this:

```
public static List<ArrayList<WorkUnit>> readInputFile(String fileName)
        throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream;
    if (fileName.equals("/textfile.txt"))
        inputStream = Util.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
    else
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream), "UTF-8"));

    String line;
    String[] splitedLine;
    List<ArrayList<WorkUnit>> activityLists =
    new ArrayList<ArrayList<WorkUnit>>();

   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        ArrayList<WorkUnit> activity = new ArrayList<WorkUnit>();
        activity.add(new WorkUnit(activityId, workerId, duration));
        activityLists.add(activity);

    }
    reader.close();

    return activityLists;

}
```

My idea was to use line.split (and mostly there is my problem) and run it in a *for* loop, sadly i failed horribly, If you have any idea how to do this in this or different way please help. The goal is to get every activityId (row number starting on 0) workerId (numbers before t),assign them durations of activities (after t in file) and add them togoether as workUnit.

Thx for any help.
Yes, I'm a noob.

**-------------------------------------------------Edit--------------------------------------------------**

Logic added for WorkUnit and splitLine logic which was working with other text file looking like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtLYT.jpg)

where number before ":" were activityIds, first numbers were workerIds and second were durations

public class WorkUnit implements Comparable {

```
int activityId;
int workerId;
int duration;

public WorkUnit(int activityId, int workerId, int duration) {

    super();
    this.activityId = activityId;
    this.workerId = workerId;
    this.duration = duration;

}

public int getActivityId() {
    return activityId;
}

public int getWorkerId() {
    return workerId;
}

public int getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    if (workerId < 10) builder.append("  "); else builder.append(" ");
    builder.append(workerId);
    if (duration < 10) builder.append("  "); else builder.append(" ");
    builder.append(duration);

    return builder.toString();

}

@Override
public int compareTo(WorkUnit object) {

    if (this.activityId == object.getActivityId()
            && this.duration == object.getDuration()
            && this.workerId == object.getWorkerId())
        return 0;

    if (this.duration > object.getDuration()) return 1;
    return -1;

}
```

}

Logic for splitLine:

```
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

       ArrayList<WorkUnit> activity = new ArrayList<WorkUnit>();

       //1st place is activity id; always ascending order 0 to n
       splitedLine = line.split("(\\s)*(:)*\\s+");
       int activityId = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine[0]);
       for (int i = 1; i < splitedLine.length; i += 2) {
           int workerId = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine[i]);
           int duration = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine[i+1]);
           activity.add(new WorkUnit(activityId, workerId, duration));
       }

       acrivityLists.add(activity);

    }
```

Comment: where in code the split logic is taking place ? I just see that you read a line and then you create a new object for WorkUnit and then over

Comment: Also share ur structure for WorkUnit... what does it comprise of... I can help u with this problem once u provide me with all these informations.

Comment: @zenwraight updated, hope these are correct informations. I would really appreciate your help, I think my problem lays in taking creating acitvityId when new line is detected, and properly splitting the string to get all the information

Comment: So u are having trouble only in the split method ? or are u having troubles in the main logic as well ?

Comment: @zenwraight I think split method is the trouble, I think I should be able to handle the rest, but I'm not 100% sure as I wasn't able to run the app after many tries, everything indicates the problem is in split string logic :)

Comment: I have one doubt... so for the row - 2 0 1 3 5 4 t 1 3 6 7 3 6   ... activity id = 2, and then the corresponding worker_id and duration should be = (0,1) , (1,3), (3,6) , (5, 7), (4,3) .. then what about the last 6 ?

Comment: @zenwraight this file standard requires this text file to have only this data and activityId is determined by number of the row, so first number (2) is actually another workerId and the last number (6) is duration of work of last worker (4)

Comment: got it.. then ur logic of this in wrong - int activityId = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine[0]); ... as activityId is equal to the line number u are reading currently

Comment: Have a look at my solution for splitted lines and let me know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I think this is what you want, in order for your logic to work correctly.

```
int activityNumber = 1;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

   ArrayList<WorkUnit> activity = new ArrayList<WorkUnit>();

   //1st place is activity id; always ascending order 0 to n
   splitedLine = line.split(" ");
   // we know that value t will be the middle element.
   int len = splitedLine.length;
   for(int i=0; i<splitedLine.length/2; i++) {
       int workerId = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine[i]);
       int duration = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine[len - i - 1]);
       activity.add(new WorkUnit(activityNumber, workerId, duration));
   }

   activityNumber++;

   acrivityLists.add(activity);

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Really appreciate it! After testing it seems like your way is working and will definitely use it with small correction to             int workLoad = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine[len/2 + 1 + i]);         there is another bug somwhere that I will have to deal with, but nonetheless this is the answer :)

Comment: I am glad that my solution was helpful to you. Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Line.split is a good idea. Implementation looks something like this:

```
String[] splitedLine = line.split(" ");
```

As argument split() takes a string which will divide your input. Then you can acces elements by using:

```
splitedLine[0];  
splitedLine[1]; etc
```